# Summing isomorphic polyhedra

Tags: general-topology, geometry

[Modified for clarity]

Let me start by stating up front that I'm not a mathematician. I'm a software engineer working on a technique that will enable better computer recognition of 3 dimensional shapes. Computers are notoriously bad at this.

I have found a way to optimize a complex block of code but it relies on an assumption that I'm uncertain of. Let's start with the following conditions:

1. Each 3-dimensional shape has sides measured with the same unit of measure (any) that are determined to be natural numbers.  For example an image of a shape measuring 1 x 5 x 2 (h,l,w) is OK but not one measuring 2 x 3.2 x 6.  That radical measurement of length is not allowed.
2. Any 3-dimensional shape is allowed. This is very important. As long as the shape's sides (straight or curved) are measured to be natural numbers (no radicals) using any arbitrary, but consistent, unit of measure, it's allowed.
3. Each of the two images being summed are of the same shape and may differ only in size, not proportion. For example an image of a shape measuring 1x5x2 (h,l,w) could be magnified (and summed with) an image measuring 2x10x4. All three dimensions must vary proportionally as integers or not at all.  Adding two identical shapes of the same exact size is also possible.

Let s1 and s2 be two identical polygons that may (or not) differ proportionally in size and meet the above criteria.

Let s3 equal the same shape with a volume equal to s1’s volume + s2’s volume.

```
    s1 + s2 = s3
```

If I assume s3's sides can never be measured to be natural numbers then I can make a clever optimization. S3’s volume will be the sum of s1’s and s2’s volume but s3’s sides will NOT be measurable as natural numbers like those of s1 and s2.

Fermat's last theorem gives me confidence only for cases where s1 and s2 are shapes with sides raised to the same power. The simplest Fermat-style example would be two cubes. If a 3x3 cube (3 to the 3rd power) having a volume of 27 is summed with a 4x4 cube (4 to the 3rd power) having a volume of 64, the resulting cube (volume 91) will ALWAYS have sides that measure to be a radical (again raised to the 3rd power because it's still a cube). If this case also holds true for 3-dimensional shapes that aren't cubes, then my optimization will work.

If there is a single case were where two identical 3-dimensional images, differing only in proportional size, and who's sides are measured to be natural numbers can be summed to result in the same shape (larger of course), equal in proportion, and whose sides are ALSO NATURAL numbers, my optimization will fail. I need the resulting shape to ALWAYS have radical lines and curves.

All tests so far indicate the resulting image (shape) will have lines and curves that measures to be radicals but I have not proved this.

If this is the case 99.999% of the time, I can't use the optimization. It must hold true %100 of the time or the code will fail. That is my question. Can Fermat's last theorem be extended to include the sums of all 3-dimensional objects meeting the above stated criteria and not just sums of shapes with integer sides raised to the same power? I believe it can but if someone could prove this or show me that it has already been proved, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $s1 + s2 = s3$?

Comment: When you sum two integers, the result is a third integer, so the third shape's volume will be an integer. Do you mean that you need the third shape to have non-integer edge lengths? That is also not the case: two cubes of volume 4 each add up to a cube of volume 8, which has sides of length $2$.

Comment: I reworded my question.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the volume of a given shape is $V$, the volume of that shape scaled by some scaling factor $s$ will always be $s^3V$ — this is regardless of what the specific structure of the shape is.  That's because the change in volume will always be measured by the determinant of the ($3\times 3$) linear transformation that converts the first shape into the scaled shape.  This means that any equation of the form $V_1+V_2=V_3$ where $V_i$ are the volumes of three isomorphic shapes will always translate into an equation of the form $s_1^3+s_2^3=s_3^3$, just as you're hoping.

(On a software-engineering note, I'm not sure why you believe that edge lengths being natural numbers will help you to optimize in any meaningful fashion — but that's a discussion for elsewhere.)

Comment: Wow, 11th in the Putnams.  Impressive.  Thank you.